# A message received from SQS by a stopped AWS ECS instance is handled by Rebus only after 5 minutes visibility timeout

Tags: amazon-sqs, rebus

I have 2 ECS instances with Rebus handling messages received from SQS. During a deployment, one ECS instance goes down, and for a couple of seconds only one ECS instance is running and handling Rebus messages. I can see in a log that a message was sent, but was handled only 5 minutes later. Here's a timeline of what happened:

ECS instance 1 being stopped at 10:05:49:

```
2021-05-21T10:05:49.239 Worker Rebus 3 worker 1 stopped
2021-05-21T10:05:49.240 Bus Rebus 3 setting number of workers to 0
2021-05-21T10:05:49.240 Removing worker Rebus 3 worker 1
2021-05-21T10:05:49.340 Disposing SQS client ("SourceContext": "Rebus.AmazonSQS.AmazonSqsTransport")
2021-05-21T10:05:49.340 Bus Rebus 3 stopped
```

A message sent at 10:05:51 from ECS instance 2:

```
2021-05-21T10:05:51.584 Sending GenerateTextToSpeechForPoiCommand -> ProductionTtsServiceApp
```

The message handled at 10:10:59 in ECS instance 3 (a newly deployed ECS instance), 5 minutes later (message visibility timeout 5 minutes):

```
2021-05-21T10:10:59.174 Dispatching GenerateTextToSpeechForPoiCommand... {messageId} to 1 handlers took 7467 ms
```

I came up with these explanations why this happened:

1. Assuming AWS ECS instances time is synchronized, the message was sent after the ECS instance 1 Rebus was stopped, and yet somehow Rebus.AmazonSqs/awssdk.sqs managed to receive the message and the message was made invisible for 5 minutes by SQS.
2. Assuming AWS ECS instances time is **not** synchronized, and the message was really received by ECS instance 1 before it was stopped (unfortunately the receive act is not logged, and the beginning of message handling is not logged as well - I think it would be useful to log both), and the message was in the middle of handling by ECS instance 1 when it was stopped. If that's the case, there should be logged message `Waiting for message handler continuations to finish...` in the log, but it's not there, so I assume the message was not handled by ECS instance 1 when it was stopped. Also, my system creates a database object just before the start of the message handling, and the database object creation time is `2021-05-21 10:10:51`, which suggests that the first message handling really started 5 minutes later.

So I think the option 1 is more plausible due to missing `Waiting for message handler continuations to finish...` message and the database object creation time in option 2.

Versions:

```
Rebus 6.4.1
Rebus.AmazonSqs 6.1.2
AWSSDK.SQS 3.5.0.36
AWSSDK.Core 3.5.1.34
```

I've now upgraded to the latest versions of Rebus and AWSSDK, and pray the issue will disappear. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, it's hard to tell what could have happened there. Do you know when message processing started in your newly deployed instance?

Comment: It started at 2021-05-21T10:10:59 , it's mentioned in the question (The message handled at 10:10:59 in ECS instance 3 (a newly deployed ECS instance))

Comment: I just realized I could replicate it locally with 2 processes, and with the right timing of sending a message and terminating a process, and hopefully could be able to replicate it. I will post my findings.

Comment: I was able to replicate it locally easily couple of times even on latest Rebus and AWSSDK nuget packages. Here's the recording of the bug: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GJXEkU1nMF4

Comment: I think it could be replicated simply by 2 processes receiving messages from the same SQS queue, and then quickly terminating one process with a wait time after disposing the bus, and immediately after the process one termination sending a message.

Comment: Hmm, it sounds like either a) Rebus is not shut down properly (but you mentioned the "(..) waiting for message handlers to finish (..)" text, so I assume that that part works like it should, or b) the code to "abandon" a message in transit (can be seen [here](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.AmazonSQS/blob/master/Rebus.AmazonSQS/AmazonSQS/AmazonSqsTransport.cs#L390-L404)) does not work like it should....

Comment: I think the message should not be in transit at all, as the message was sent after the process 1 Rebus disposal. It seems to me that Rebus has been disposed, but some AWSSDK.SQS stuff has not been properly disposed and received the message.

Comment: I discovered an explanation which I think applies here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/796#issuecomment-375494537 : "So even though a message is sent after the previous ReceiveMessage request has been canceled the socket from the previous receive is still open. SQS replies over the old socket with the new message, considers it received, and subjects the message to the visibility timeout." The suggested workaround not passing cancellationToken into sqsClient.ReceiveMessageAsync() but passing in CancellationToken.None works for me: http://prntscr.com/13fyfhv

Comment: The downside is that the process now terminates not immediately, but it takes about 1min (I have 4 Rebus instances, and each disposes in about 15s with the workaround). If I decide to go with this workaround, I would need to increase ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT from 30s to at least 1min 30s to make sure the ECS instance is not forcefully stopped.

Comment: I created a github issue for this: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.AmazonSQS/issues/35